# File and Folder Operations in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I am writing a todo list manager program in C++ and would like to do the following:

1. Check if a directory exists in the program's working directory, if not create it
2. If it does exist, get a list of .txt files from it.
3. Be able to create/delete .txt files from this directory

I have tried using `boost/filesystem.hpp` but can't seem to figure it out (or how to get it to link using g++). Below is an example of what I have tried (assume proper `#includes`'s, `int main`, etc):

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> findLists(void){
    std::vector<std::string> lists;
    std::string temp;
    char dir[ MAX_PATH ];
    std::string(dir, GetModuleFileName(NULL, dir, MAX_PATH));
    dir = dir.substr(0,dir.find_last_of( "\\/" ));
    path p(dir);
    for(auto i = directory_iterator(p); i != directory_iterator(); i++){
        if(!is_directory(i->path())){
            temp = i->path().filename().string();
            if(temp.compare(0,temp.find(".")+1,".txt")){
                temp = temp.substr(0,temp.find("."));
            }
            lists.push_back(temp);
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
    }

    return lists;
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in standard C++ for any of that stuff.  You need to use a library instead, such as [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), or else use the OS platform's underlying filesystem APIs directly (for instance, on Windows, `GetFileAttribute()`, `CreateDirectory()`, `FindFirstFile()`/`FindNextFile()`, `CreateFile()`, and `DeleteFile()`).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I understand, I'm just not sure how to implement it. (Nice name, btw.)

Comment: If you are having trouble with specific code snippets, then please show the actual code.  But don't ask for general suggestions/advise, that is not what this site is meant for, and it is likely to get your question closed as off-topic

Comment: I hesitated to add it, since it doesn't really do what I want...at all.

Comment: Then you need to [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37016661/edit) to explain exactly what you do want, show what you have attempted to do so far, and how it is not doing what you need it to do.

Comment: `GetModuleFileName()` returns a full path **and** filename.  You need to strip off the filename before you can then pass the remaining folder path to `directory_iterator()`.  Also, `std::string(dir, GetModuleFileName(NULL, dir, MAX_PATH));` is creating a temporary unnamed `string` and copying `dir` into it, but the temporary is never used afterward. Also, `if(temp.substr(temp.find(".")+1)` is incomplete and not compilable as shown, which means this is not a **copy/paste** of your real code. Even then, `find(".")` finds the first ".", but there may be multiple `"."` characters in the filename.

Comment: I believe it has that, but was misformatted (was trying to edit at the same time you did)

Comment: `dir = dir.substr(0,dir.find_last_of( "\\/" ));` should take care of the file name. And it is, in fact, an actual copy/paste. That line is not complete as I stopped when I could not get boost to link to test its functionality.

Comment: `dir` is a `char[]`, not a `std::string`. You are still converting `dir` to a `std::string` incorrectly, and then trying to call `substr()` on the `char[]`. This code **DOES NOT COMPILE**. In any case, since you are using the Win32 API to get the path+filename, you can use [`PathRemoveFileSpec()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773748.aspx) to strip the filename before then converting the path to a `std::string`.  Or, create a `boost::filesystem::path` from the full path+filename and then use `path::remove_filename()`.

Comment: piece of advice, get your boost installation to work, and then it'll be a piece of cake

Comment: @dau_sama that is what I am attempting to do, hence why I posted a question on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

From [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html)

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  path p (argv[1]);   // p reads clearer than argv[1] in the following code

  if (exists(p))    // does p actually exist?
  {
    if (is_regular_file(p))        // is p a regular file?   
      cout << p << " size is " << file_size(p) << '\n';

    else if (is_directory(p))      // is p a directory?
      cout << p << "is a directory\n";

    else
      cout << p << "exists, but is neither a regular file nor a directory\n";
  }
  else
    cout << p << "does not exist\n";

  return 0;
}
```

You have all the facilities you need in there. This is only a starting point, but you should be able to get through it pretty quickly.

Comment: That actually does really help me. This does not allow me to 1) find the working directory. 2) Search for another directory. 3) Open that and search that directory's contents for .txt files.